# How to output to same line with relation information same table?

Tags: sql-server

This is my current SQL Server query and almost what I want to do:

```
select "dokumentgruppe" + ', ' + convert(varchar(10), dokumentgruppenr) 
    + ', ' + 'Parent:' + convert(varchar(10), parentgruppenr) 
    as "Dokumentgruppe"
from "dbo"."dokumentgruppe"
where aktiv = '1'
order by "Dokumentgruppe"
```

It gives me this result:

```
Budsjetter, 29, Parent:0
E-post, 36, Parent:0
Fyllearrester, 40, Parent:38
Inngående, 42, Parent:36
JuksOgFanteri, 38, Parent:0
Legeattester, 39, Parent:38
Ligning, 26, Parent:0
Periodiske regnskapsrapporter, 30, Parent:0
Permanente opplysninger, 23, Parent:0
Produksjon Fakturering, 33, Parent:0
Produksjon Lønn, 32, Parent:0
Produksjon Regnskap, 31, Parent:0
```

The thing is, I want to show the actual **name** of the `Parentgruppe` instead of `ParentgruppeID`. The `Parentgruppe` has an ID and a corresponding name to it.

Like this example:

```
Legeattester, 39, Parent:*JuksOgFanteri
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this result by joining the table to itself.

```
select c.dokumentgruppe 
    + ', ' + convert(varchar(10), c.dokumentgruppenr) 
    + ', ' + 'Parent:' + isnull(p.dokumentgruppe,'') 
    + ', ' + convert(varchar(10), c.parentgruppenr) 
    as Dokumentgruppe
from dbo.dokumentgruppe as c
  left join dbo.dokumentgruppe as p on c.parentgruppenr=p.dokumentgruppenr
where c.aktiv = '1'
order by c.Dokumentgruppe
```

This is an adjacency list style heirarchy, you can find a good introduction to them here: [Sql Server Bible Sample Chapter 17: Traversing Hierarchies](http://www.sqlserverbible.com/files/sqlserver2008bible_ch17.pdf)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your effort in answering this!

Comment: Sorry, wasn't supposed to post the previous answer.. This is complete answer:
Hi, thank you very much for your effort in answering this! I tested it, and it didn't work at the moment. I got this: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Avtale og fullmakter' to data type int.

I will try to figure it out (I have tried a lot today, but since I am a n00b with this, I have not got it to work yet. It seems I must do some more converting.
Will give it more time soon :)
/Anders

Comment: I think it should be fixed now: I missed the `nr` in `dokumentgruppenr` in `c.parentgruppenr=p.dokumentgruppenr` that's what was throwing your error.

Comment: You are an angel! Thank you very much! :-)
/Anders